# Error: android defines classes that conflict with classes now provided by Android , when we start to generate release build

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I had several libraries conflict issues. That i resolved by adding

configurations {

```
all {
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
    exclude module: 'commons-logging'
    exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    exclude module: 'xmlParserAPIs'
    exclude module: 'xpp3'
    exclude module: 'opengl-api'
}
```

}

But still following error present. And i am unable to build signed apk.
I have tried project clean/rebuild option.

**Error: android defines classes that conflict with classes now provided by Android. Solutions include finding newer versions or alternative libraries that don't have the same problem (for example, for httpclient use HttpUrlConnection or okhttp instead), or repackaging the library using something like jarjar. [DuplicatePlatformClasses]**

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you post your full build.gradle.

Comment: So how did you fix this issue?

Comment: with the help of gradlew dependencies , i found all libraries, those are creating conflicts.  Because some of library has internal dependency of other libraries.  So i exclude libraries in my build.gradle file.  After clean code. it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Problem**

How to see which dependency is creating conflicts. It is same like shooting in dark.

**Solution**

Some AS plugin that will show you which projects dependency hierarchy. You can find where issue presents exactly and solve that.

[Gradle View](https://github.com/rholder/gradle-view) is an Android Studio plugin that you can install and show dependency hierarchy.

[image]

[Methods Count](https://web.archive.org/web/20171214202859/http://www.methodscount.com/plugins) is another plugin, it also shows dependency tree.

[image]

Comment: with the help of gradlew dependencies , i found all libraries what i need to exclude.

Answer (score 3):

The error may be comes from different module but if issue is httpcomp... or xpp3 then
I just add these lines of code in app Gradle

```
dependencies {
......
  configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
        implementation.exclude group: "org.apache.httpcomponents", module: "httpclient"
    }
}
```

done

Comment: Great. It build successfully. I placed this section as it is in "app\build.gradle". Many thanks!